# Cannot read Registry Value - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am banging my head around a constant error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when reading the value of a registry key. please give me your suggestions of how to resolve.

```
string regkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{A8EC0CC0-AD8D-4244-B080-424EDF7A7634}";
object thekey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regkey).GetValue("DisplayName");
TraktorVersion = thekey.ToString();
```

where TraktorVersion is a string.

Comment: Could you show how "TraktorVersion" is defined prior to this reference?

Comment: Hi Joshua, it is defined in the same class as string TraktorVersion;

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that key exist in the registry? Check that thekey is not being set to null.

```
string regkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{A8EC0CC0-AD8D-4244-B080-424EDF7A7634}";
object thekey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regkey).GetValue("DisplayName");    
if(thekey!=null)    
   TraktorVersion = thekey.ToString();
```

Comment: The key is copied and pasted from the registry and DisplayName value has data inside. I made a test with GetValueNames and only 3 values were returned. In the key there are around 10 values which confuses me even more.

Comment: You may need elevated rights to see the other values. Try right clicking on your app and run as administrator

Comment: Is your application 32-bit running on 64-bit workstation? Then some keys may not be available and you should look in Software\Wow6432Node regkey.

Comment: Hi jbriggs, the put if statement if (thekey != null)
            {
                TraktorVersion = thekey.ToString();
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(TraktorVersion);
            }   , compiled and ran with admin rights. the message box didn't appear

Comment: That's because the key didn't exist or is isn't accessible. @VitaliyK could be right also. What are you using to view the registry?

Comment: on the command prompt you can run 
reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /reg:32
If that shows the same 3 values then you know it's a 32bit vs 64bit thing